# Returning ffprobe metadata to another function using fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to use `fluent-ffmpeg`'s `ffprobe` to get the metadata of a file and add it to a list, but I want to separate the process of getting the metadata from the method related to checking the file, mostly because the `addFileToList()` function is quite long as is and the `ffprobe` routine is quite long as well.

I've tried the following code, but it doesn't give the results I'm expecting:

```js
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    getVideoMetadata (file) {
      const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
      ffmpeg.ffprobe(file.name, (err, metadata) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(metadata)  // this shows the metadata just fine
          return metadata
        }
      })
    },
    addFileToList (file) {
      // file checking routines
      console.log(this.getVideoMetadata(file))  // this returns null
      item.metadata = this.getVideoMetadata(file)
      // item saving routines
    }    
  }
}
```

I've already tried to nest the `getVideoMetadata()` routines inside `addFileToList()`, and it works, but not as intended, because the actions are carried, but not the first time, only the second time. It seems to be an async issue, but I don't know how can I tackle this.

What can I do? Should I stick to my idea of decoupling `getVideoMetadata()` or should I nest it inside `addFileToList()` and wrestle with `async`/`await`?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to the ffprobe race condition issue?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that probing for metadata introduces a race condition, so we should structure the code so that the flow continues after the callback:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
var data
ffmpeg.ffprobe(file.name, (err, metadata) => {
    if (!err) {
        data = metadata
        continueDoingStuff()
    }
})
```